# Configure Nvidia on Linux Mint to turn on three screens

Tags: nvidia, multi-monitor

How should I configure this menu to can turn on all screens?

[image]

```
**Info**
*-display           
description: VGA compatible controller
product: G98M [Quadro NVS 160M]
vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
version: a1
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
resources: irq:31 memory:f5000000-f5ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff            
memory:f2000000-f3ffffff ioport:df00(size=128) memory:f4000000-f401ffff
```

@terdon

> Have you tried simply setting the Dell screen to "on"?

Right now I was using the Dell and 22" screens. When I tried turn on the screen the laptop, LPL (1440x900), choose the option Resolution (to turn on is), and apply settings I received this message:

[image]

[image]

If I choose the option "Auto Fix" the 22" screen turn off and turn on LPL and the Dell remains turn on.

> Are you sure your card actually supports running 3 monitors?

I don't know if my card support this number of the screens. But I tested the same settings with the another pc, Asus with ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5470 Graphics 1 GB, and the Linux Mint (exactly the same version) and I was the same problem. I know which this laptop, Asus, some time ago, I could turn on this both screens. One of them through HDMI and another VGA.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried simply setting the Dell screen to "on"? Are you sure your card actually supports running 3 monitors? I'm guessing it probably doesn't.

Comment: Hello, anyone can help me? thanks

Comment: I still think your card can probably not support three monitors. I recently tried to do the same thing on my laptop and concluded that the card can take it. If you have Windows installed with your card's proprietary driver, try the three screens there. If it still doesn't work it's probably not possible. In the end, I chose to have the laptop screen off and use the other two.

Comment: To curiosity, Why do you choose this set?

Comment: Because the laptop's is a 15in screen while the two external ones are 22 and 24.

Answer (score 0):

I do this on Ubuntu 16.04 with a Dell Laptop. Configure it in the Ubuntu Settings. Sometimes it crashes when I apply the settings. But after a few attempts it works every day (I disconnect the external screens every day when I leave the office and take the notebook with me)

[image]

One Display is BUilt in, one is connected via HDMI and one via Mini-Display-Port. Nvidia-PRIME must be turned on (Optimus graphics) The internal Intel-graphics is not able to handle 3 displays.